# Remove dates array between start date and end date in php

Tags: php, datetime

I want to find an optimized way to remove dates between start date and end date in php, below how i handle it but seems timeout when there is too many days :

```
/**
* Get list of dates from start date and end date
* @param {string} start
* @param {string} end
* @param {string} format
* @return array
*/

function _getDatesFromRange($start, $end, $format = 'd/m/Y') { 
  
    // Declare an empty array 
    $array = array(); 
          
    // Variable that store the date interval 
    // of period 1 day 
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); 
    $realEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $end); 
    $realEnd->add($interval); 
    $period = new DatePeriod(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $start), $interval, $realEnd); 
    // Use loop to store date into array 
    foreach($period as $date) { 
        $array[] = $date->format($format);  
     } 
      
    // Return the array elements 
    return $array; 
} 

/**
* Flat an array
* @param {array} array
* @return array
*/
function _flatten($array) {
  $return = array();
  array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
  return $return;
}

// List of dates
$bookings = array(
    array(
        'bookable' => 'no', 
        'from' => '2020-08-01',
        'to' => '2020-08-05'
    ),
    array(
        'bookable' => 'no', 
        'from' => '2020-08-15',
        'to' => '2020-08-18'
    ),
    array(
        'bookable' => 'yes', 
        'from' => '2020-08-01',
        'to' => '2020-08-31'
    )
);
```

So to list all dates and get bookable list, i do like this :

```
foreach($bookings as $booking){
    if($booking['bookable'] === 'yes'){
        // Get an array of list of dates between start and end
        $bookable[] = _getDatesFromRange($booking['from'], $booking['to']);
    } else {
        $not_bookable[] = _getDatesFromRange($booking['from'], $booking['to']);
    }        
}

if(is_array($bookable) && is_array($not_bookable)) {
    $output = array_diff(_flatten($bookable), _flatten($not_bookable));
    print_r($output);
}
```

You can test all from this url [bookable dates demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/780bce41a9181a7dc3b651ecbcc12fdb012da99a), i have 2000 products and some products have a large intervals between start and end date like below, and in this case i get timeout execution, so how i can optimise above code ?

```
$bookings = array(
    array(
        'bookable' => 'no', 
        'from' => '2020-08-01',
        'to' => '2020-08-05'
    ),
    array(
        'bookable' => 'no', 
        'from' => '2020-08-15',
        'to' => '2020-08-18'
    ),
    array(
        'bookable' => 'yes', 
        'from' => '2050-08-01',
        'to' => '2050-08-31'
    )
);
```

Thanks for you helps

Comment: Why do you need to store all these dates in two large arrays? In other words, what are you doing with these arrays after you've created them, and could you do that once for each booking item instead?

Comment: I have to check if a given date is between output array (i have a date picker to enter a search date)

Comment: Why can't you process each date range as you calculate it, rather than calculating them all and then processing them all together?

Comment: Hi what do you mean? have you an example ?

Comment: I would start by [configuring PHP to prevent your script from timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909191/prevent-timeout-during-large-request-in-php)

Comment: Hi, not every client can configure his own php

Comment: Are you saying that `set_time_limit()` is disabled in your PHP installation?